# Xamarin.Android how to get current position of cursor in an Edittext

Tags: xamarin.android, android-edittext

In android there is a method getSelectionStart(), in xamarin.Android do not exists. Is there another way to accomplish this in Xamarin.android?

Answer (score 1):

> Xamarin.Android how to get current position of cursor in an Edittext

You can code like this :

```
var position = et.SelectionStart;
```

Usually the API are the same as it in Java.

Comment: @foluis, if this can help you, could you please mark it as an answer?